# matlab: structural data and multi-level indexing

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, structure, multi-level

I have a simple problem with structures.

Lets create:

```
x(1).a(:, :) = magic(2);
x(2).a(:, :) = magic(2)*2;
x(3).a(:, :) = magic(2)*3;
```

how to list a(1, 1) from all x-es?

i wanted to do it like:

```
x(1, :).a(1,1)
```

but there is an error "Scalar index required for this type of multi-level indexing."

How to approach it? I know I can do it with a loop, but that's probably the worst solution :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the best datastructure to use if this is the sort of query you'd like to make on it, precisely because this sort of indexing cannot be done directly.

However, here is one approach that works:

```
cellfun(@(X) X(1,1), {x.a})
```

The syntax `{x.a}` converts `x` from a 'struct array' into a cell array.  Then we use `cellfun` to apply a function as a map over the cell array.  The anonymous function `@(X) X(1,1)` takes one argument `X` and returns `X(1,1)`.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to have f.ex. x(1, :).a(:,1)?

Answer (score 2):

You can also get your data in this way:

```
B = cat(3,x.a);
out = reshape(B(1,1,:),1,[]);
```

By the way, loops are not evil. Sometimes they are even faster than vectorized indexation. Try it both ways, see what suits you best in terms of:

- Speed - use the profiler to check
- Code clarity - depends on the context. Sometimes vectorized code looks better, sometimes the opposite.